# java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:97)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rbenv

i am running RAILS application in local rbenv   webrick server   , i am getting this error often and the server stops , please advice me

```
 java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:97)
    Exception in thread "RubyThread-3337: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/server.rb:103" java.lang.InternalError: identity=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L)=>{
        t3:L=Species_L.argL0(a0:L);
        t4:L=ValueConversions.identity(t3:L);t4:L}
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:97)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:460)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.checkInvocationCounter(LambdaForm.java:634)
        at rubyjit.WEBrick::GenericServer$$start_thread_7B70F846F4B96CB34E341FFAE1CC88FEEAA8EA95520186210.chained_1_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(/usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/server.rb:191)
        at rubyjit.WEBrick::GenericServer$$start_thread_7B70F846F4B96CB34E341FFAE1CC88FEEAA8EA95520186210.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(/usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/server.rb)
        at rubyjit.WEBrick::GenericServer$$start_thread_7B70F846F4B96CB34E341FFAE1CC88FEEAA8EA95520186210.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/server.rb:181)
        at rubyjit$WEBrick::GenericServer$$start_thread_7B70F846F4B96CB34E341FFAE1CC88FEEAA8EA95520186210$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$WEBrick::GenericServer$$start_thread_7B70F846F4B96CB34E341FFAE1CC88FEEAA8EA95520186210$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:163)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.call(CompiledBlock19.java:91)
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:89)
        at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:261)
        at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:213)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:98)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    [2014-04-19 16:37:20] ERROR Java::JavaLang::InternalError: identity=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L)=>{
        t3:L=Species_L.argL0(a0:L);
        t4:L=ValueConversions.identity(t3:L);t4:L}
        java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:97)
    [2014-04-19 16:37:21] ERROR Java::JavaLang::InternalError: guard=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L)=>{
        t3:I=MethodHandle(AbstractScript,ThreadContext)boolean(a1:L,a2:L);
        t4:L=MethodHandleImpl.selectAlternative(t3:I,(MethodHandle(AbstractScript,ThreadContext)IRubyObject),(MethodHandle(AbstractScript,ThreadContext)IRubyObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

The permgen is a location in memory where loaded classes (and apparently, in this case, lambdas) are stored. It does not grow in size by default. You may pass the following startup options to Java (or put it in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable):

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

to allow it to unload classes and try to collect PermGen space. Of course, if you need a lot of classes loaded *at one time*, you can increase the PermGen space with

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=SIZE
```

128M is a reasonable value, though I have no way of knowing how class-and-lambda-heavy your application is.

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi You'll need to give more details as to it not working. Is the issue delayed? How much heap/non-heap used?